# Group by Returns Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query below returns multiple lines instead of aggregating the count. What am I doing wrong.

```
select case when s.Customer is not null then 'Paid' else 'Free' END as Paid_Free,
       Status,case when CompleteDate < '4/1/2018' then '1H' else '2H' end as Busy, 
       count(*) userCount
from CompletesCur OS 
   left outer join  Sales s on S.Cust = ID
WHERE s.ReturnYear = 2017
  and s.MediaType = 'Online'
  and os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017
  and s.ReturnYear = s.TransactionTaxYear2
  and s.ProductGroup in ('Fed','State','Phone Support', 'Import')
GROUP by s.Customer,Status,CompleteDate
```

Results:

```
Paid_Free   Status          Busy   Usercount
Paid      Returning Yr3+     2H      2
Paid      Returning Yr3+     2H      1
Paid      Returning Yr3+     1H      1
Paid      Returning Yr3+     1H      1
Paid      Returning Yr2+     2H      2
Paid      Returning Yr2+     2H      2
```

Results Requested:

```
Paid_Free    Status            Busy    UserCount
Paid        Returning Yr3+      2H       3
Paid        Returning Yr3+      1H       2
Paid        Returning Yr2+      2H       4
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data

Comment: The s table conditions in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN to return regular INNER JOIN result. Move those conditions to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Or switch to INNER JOIN?)

Comment: And I don't think `CompleteDate` datatype is `DATE` because of `'4/1/2018'`

Comment: @sami if completedate is a date sqlserver will convert '4/1/2018' string to a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like below

```
with cte
(
select case when s.Customer is not null then 'Paid' else 'Free' END as Paid_Free,
Status,case when CompleteDate < '4/1/2018' then '1H' else '2H' end as Busy, 
count(*) userCount
     from CompletesCur OS 
   left outer join  Sales s on S.Cust = ID
                  WHERE s.ReturnYear = '2017'
                  and MediaType = 'Online'
                  and os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017
                  and s.ReturnYear = s.TransactionTaxYear2
                  and s.ProductGroup in ('Fed','State','Phone Support', 'Import')

                  GROUP by s.Customer,Status,CompleteDate
) select Paid_Free,Status,Busy, sum(userCount) from cte
  group by Paid_Free,Busy,Status
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by what you're expecting in your output

```
select          case
                    when s.Customer is not null then 'Paid'
                else 'Free'
                end        as Paid_Free
                , Status
                , case
                      when CompleteDate < '4/1/2018' then '1H'
                  else '2H'
                  end      as Busy
                , count(*) userCount
from            CompletesCur OS
left outer join Sales        s on S.Cust = ID
where           s.ReturnYear = '2017'
and             MediaType = 'Online'
and             os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017
and             s.ReturnYear = s.TransactionTaxYear2
and             s.ProductGroup in ('Fed', 'State', 'Phone Support', 'Import')
group by        case
                    when s.Customer is not null then 'Paid'
                else 'Free'
                end
                , Status
                , case
                      when CompleteDate < '4/1/2018' then '1H'
                  else '2H'
                  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group by` the non-aggregated expressions in the `select` (and generally *only* those).  Repeating complex expressions can get cumbersome, which is why I like defining new fields in subqueries or using `apply:

```
select v.Paid_Free, Status, v.Busy, 
       count(*) as userCount
from CompletesCur OS left join
     Sales s
     on S.Cust = ID cross apply
     (values ( case when s.Customer is not null then 'Paid' else 'Free' END,
               case when CompleteDate < '2018-04-01' then '1H' else '2H' end
             )
     ) v(Paid_Free, Busy)
WHERE s.ReturnYear = '2017' and  -- is this really a string?
      MediaType = 'Online' and   -- what table is this from?
      os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017 and
      s.ReturnYear = s.TransactionTaxYear2 and
      s.ProductGroup in ('Fed', 'State', 'Phone Support', 'Import')
GROUP by v.Paid_Free, Status, v.Busy;
```

Other notes:

- You should qualify *all* column names, including `Status` and `MediaType`.
- Is `ReturnYear` a number or a string?  If a number, do not use quotes for the comparison value.
- I changed the date constant to a standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
group by 
  case when s.Customer is not null then 'Paid' else 'Free' END,
  Status,
  case when CompleteDate < '4/1/2018' then '1H' else '2H' end
```

Otherwise you are still creating groups made of distinct customers and dates.

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong?

While the other answers explain what to do to fix the problem, you specifically asked what you did wrong and I hope this answer will help you understand that..

Make this change to your select, and you'll see:

```
select 
   case when s.Customer is not null then 'Paid' else 'Free' END as Paid_Free,
   Status,
   case when CompleteDate < '4/1/2018' then '1H' else '2H' end as Busy, 
   --my additions
   s.customer,
   CompleteDate,
   count(*) userCount
```

No more duplicate rows! (I didn't squish the duplicates, I added the columns that were actually grouped, so you'll still get all the unexpected rows, but it will be easy to see *why* they appeared.)

The combination of **customer/status/completedate** is unique but you transform the data after it has been grouped. The result of transforming this data is that it becomes less precise - there are thousands of dates before 4/1/2018 but you effectively converted it to a boolean value (is-before or is-after). All your rows that were dates of 3/29/2018, 3/28/2018 etc.. and were formerly unique, now all became the same value, hence the *apparent* duplicates

Hiding info/losing precision in this way, creates duplicates